# Counting columns if certain Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tblTitles` that I am attempting to run a select query on. I would like to select a count  based reports are there with `IdState` and do a count on how many of those titles belong to `IsOnSaleCountId` which would be if that column has an id of 1

Here is an example of the table:

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| IdState | RegionId |       Title       |   IsOnSaleId    |
+---------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
|      22 |        1 |   Online Shopping |               0 |
|      22 |        1 |   Retail Shopping |               1 |
|      22 |        1 |   Pick Up         |               0 |
|         |          |                   |                 |
+---------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

My expected outcome should read that IdState of 22 has 3 reports and 1 report is onSale due to the 1 integer in the second row. Which would look similar to this:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| IdState | ReportCount | IsOnSaleCount |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|      22 |           3 |             1 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

I am having issues when doing a select statement with this count. The IsOnSaleCount is identical to the  ReportCount number which they should not be.

I believe this is the case due to my line of code of `case when count(i.IsOnSaleId) > 0 THEN count(1) Else 0 End as IsOnSaleCount`

Is this something that I can do in a `SELECT` query?

Here is an example of my query :

```
select
                        i.IdState,
                        count(i.RegionId) as ReportCount,
                        case when count(i.IsOnSaleId) > 0 THEN count(1) Else 0 End as IsOnSaleCount,                    
                        0 as EnterpriseReportCount,
                        i.IdReportCollection_PK_PrimaryCollection
    
            from        IBIS_Local.dbo.tblindustry i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the count:

```
count(i.IsOnSaleId) as IsOnSaleCount,
```

If you just want a 0/1 flag, you could do:

```
sign(count(i.IsOnSaleId)) as IsOnSaleCount,
```

Comment: I would like to only get the count of `i.IsOnSaleId` if it equals 1; is that what you mean by the `0/1` flag?

Comment: @maimok . . . Can it take on any other values?  If not, you can just sum it -- assuming it is some sort of number value.  A 0/1 flag would return 1 if the count were 1 or more.

Comment: that column is treated as a boolean so it will only be 1 or 0. So based on your advice, I'll go with the sum route

Comment: @maimok . . . The only caveat is that if you are storing it as a bit (which I don't recommend), you need to convert it to a number:  `sum(convert(int,  IsOnSaleId))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('stack.report') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE stack.report
CREATE TABLE stack.report ( IdState TINYINT, RegionID TINYINT, Title VARCHAR(50), IsOnSaleId INT)
INSERT INTO stack.report
VALUES 
(22,1,'Online Shopping', 0)
, (22,1,'Retail Shopping', 1)
, (22,1,'Pick Up', 0)

SELECT *, CONVERT(TINYINT, IsOnSaleId) isonsaleint FROM stack.report

SELECT IdState, COUNT(*) ReportCount, SUM(IsOnSaleId) OnSaleCount 
FROM stack.report
GROUP BY IdState 
ORDER BY IdState
```

Result

```
IdState | ReportCount   | OnSaleCount
22      | 3             | 1
```

The SUM works if IsOnSaleId is an INT, SMALLINT or TINYINT.  If IsOnSalesId datatype is BIT (commonly used for flags), then you will need to convert to one of the int types like this SUM(CONVERT(INT, IsOnSaleId))